# installing RASPBIAN 3.18 + additional packages into Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth

I've just installed RASPBIAN 3.18 and next packages:

```
wget http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/b/bluez/bluez_4.99- 2_armhf.deb
wget http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/libc/libcap- ng/libcap-ng0_0.6.6-2_armhf.deb
wget http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/r/radvd/radvd_1.8.5- 1_armhf.deb
wget -O kernel.zip http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/nordic/download_resource/41602/5/28710770
unzip kernel.zip
sudo dpkg -i radvd_1.8.5-1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libcap-ng0_0.6.6-2_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i bluez_4.99-2_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.17.4-release+_1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.17.4-release+_1_armhf.deb
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

Add the following line:

```
kernel=vmlinuz-3.17.4-release+ to config.txt
```

save and exit

```
sudo reboot
```

and when I restart I got an screen more or less as the print screen attached. Any idea ?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome! Since my Pi also shows this colorful image in the beginning of the boot process I have to assume that in your case it's not moving on beyond that?

Comment: Hi !  true that's it :-)  ACT led is flashing but nothing happens

Comment: Since you are installing a different kernel than what is supplied in Raspbian - can you comment on why you are switching? You might want to insert the SD card into a linux computer, open up /boot/config.txt, comment out the kernel line and see if everything boots up fine then ....

Comment: I am following this tutorial: IoT_SDK_step_by_step.pdf  https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/24554/do-you-have-any-impressive-iot-demo-example/

Comment: I presume you got through this by now but for posterity, there is some documentation regarding the flashing LED: http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern